# Do guidelines exist for the second parameter of `response.writeHead` when submitting the errored response to client?

Tags: node.js, http

I tried to send the below message

```sh
Invalid query parameters detected:


=== Error No. 1 ==========
Required property is missing

●　Property / element: 'Deserialized query parameters of http://127.0.0.1:90/api/categories route.paginationPageNumber'
This property is 'undefined' while has been marked as required.

●　Property / element specification:
{
  "type": "number",
  "required": true,
  "numbersSet": "NATURAL_NUMBER"
}
●　Actual value: undefined
●　Value before first pre-validation modification: undefined

< etc. >
```

via

```
response. // (is "http.ServerResponse")
   writeHead(HTTP_StatusCodes.badRequest, errorMessage).
   end();
```

in `errorMessage` variable . Below NodeJS error occured:

```
Caught error:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in statusMessage
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:322:11)
    // ...
```

I have no idea on which character NodeJS complains about (possibly slashes), but I suppose what I am using the second parameter of `writeHead` improperly. If so, there are two questions:

- Which `errorMessage` must be like? Just "Bad request" or "Unauthorized"?
- Where I should append above login message instead?

Comment: My first guess would be the non-ascii bullets. Likely easy enough to try the suspicious characters on their own (bullets, newlines, etc). Personally I'd think a giant thing like this belongs in the body, as something machine-readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this for [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#responsewriteheadstatuscode-statusmessage-headers)

You can send a response like this

```js
let body = error_message; // or whatever response you want to send back to the sender

response
  .writeHead(STATUS_CODE, {
    'Content-Type': 'your_header_content_type'
  }).end(body);
```

As for the status codes, you can refer the [mozilla convention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)  here (which is quite widely used)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Excurse me, what is the `body` in your example? Is it the long message content?

Comment: Yes, its optional. You can omit it and not send it if you don't want to

Comment: I have updated the ans with body included. In your case, you can send errorMessage as the body